# How do I detect why am not getting any output

Tags: c

While writing a program to find palindromes which is product of two 3 digit number my code compiled but did not gave any output.

code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n, m, o, c = 0;
    for (n = 100; n < 1000; n++)
    {
        for (m = 100; m < 1000; m++)
        {
            o = m * n;

            while (o > 0)
            {
                c = c * 10 + o % 10;
                o /= 10;
            }

            if (c == (m * n))
            {
                printf("%d", m * n);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Start by making the code more readable by properly indenting it. It will help to "detect" many potential issues.

Comment: You might start by limiting the range to search. Knowing some numbers that meet your requirement will help.

Comment: You should run your program in a debugger and verify if the variables hold the values you expect. Looking closer at changes of `c` might be a good start.

Comment: BTW: Your question body does not contain a question. Do you want to know what's wrong or how you can find such errors (as your title suggests)?

Answer (score 1):

You're not resetting `c` anywhere. It's just going to grow larger and larger, quickly exceeding the limits of `int` and then you have undefined behavior.

Put `c = 0;` before the `while (o > 0) {`. Also it would help to have some whitespace after the `%d` in your `printf` call.

Comment: thank you now it worked, stacks overflow is awesome:)

Answer (score 0):

Step through using a debugger, such as gdb.

Step through each line using n, and keep printing the variables that you are interested in.

Sometimes it is more helpful to `disp` the variables.

I'm sure you will soon "see" the issue.